# Git push to google cloud compute engine

Tags: git, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP, and am trying to git push my repo to a GCP Compute Engine running Debian.

I download the *gcloud command tool* and ran

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

Which gave me as ouput `ssh golub-vm.us-west1-a.golub-182114`.
After that I did an

```
gcloud compute ssh golub-vm
```

And created a remote bare git repo at `~/apps/golub/golub.git` So I added it as a remote to my local repository via:

```
git remote add gsrvr golub@golub-vm.us-west1-a.golub-182114:/apps/golub/golub.git
```

and tried a push, but I'm getting an

```
D:\golub>git push gsrvr master
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

**Note:** I made sure that `/apps/golub/golub.git` is owned by `golub:root`. What am I doing wrong?

Oh and I tried to use `gcloud compute scp` to copy a local file to the server, it works fine, so it shouldn't be any issues with the ownership, right?

I'm running a Bitnami LAMP image. So the full path would be `/opt/bitnami/apps/golub/golub.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first:

```
ssh -Tv golub@golub-vm.us-west1-a.golub-182114
```

That will show you what ssh public/private keys ssh is trying in order to open a remote secure session.

Consider that [gcloud compute config-ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh) is likely to create a ~/.ssh/config file, which means the ssh URL to use is *not* `user@server` but an alias seen in that file.

> Each instance will be given an alias of the form `NAME.ZONE.PROJECT`.
>   For example, if example-instance resides in `us-central1-a`, you can SSH to it by running:

```
ssh example-instance.us-central1-a.MY-PROJECT
```

Comment: There is no issue with the SSH, I can connect just fine via ssh using Git Bash (I am on Windows) like you requested. I tried changing it so I use the serve and username in the URL like this: `golub@domain.com:/apps/golub/golub.git (push)` But I'm getting the same error. The SSH key is right, I enabled logs for it in `/.ssh/config` and set `LogLevel DEBUG3`. I tried different things with the path, using both relative and absolute ones. Like using `/home/golub/apps/golub/golub.git` None of them work. Could it be an issue with the permissions? I'm pretty sure `golub` can RW to the folder

Comment: @EdisGolubich do you have a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file? And if yes, what is its content?